# HTTP/HTTPS over TcpListener to allow both on same port

Tags: sockets, http, https, tcplistener

Due to business limitations we need to serve both HTTP & HTTPS requests on the same port.
As I understand this is not possible at the HttpListener level.

So I'm trying to do this with TcpListener, by reading the first bytes of the request to understand whether it's an HTTP or HTTPS request and handle & respond to it accordingly. In case it's HTTPS I can use the SslStream, however this  does not include HTTP layer data.

Since I already received data from the socket, I can no longer use HttpListener.
Also, I prefer not to implement the HTTP layer related code by myself.

Are there any HTTP classes in the .NET framework which can do the parsing of the request & help build the response to send back on the socket?

Comment: You probably want to "peek" at the first few bytes of data on the socket without consuming them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5906243/238704).

Comment: @JamesKPolk but then I would need to keep starting and stopping the HttpListener on every incoming request to switch its prefix between http and https (after peeking the data with the TcpListener). Isn't there a better way?

Comment: You can't do it with an httplistener, you can only do it with a tcplistener. I don't understand your comment about starting and stopping the httplistener, you can't use a tcplistener and an httplistener on the same port and ipadress.

Comment: As mentioned in the original question, I don't want to manually write HTTP layer handling code which would  be the case when working with TcpListener alone.